# Anyone have an example of maintaining employee hierarchy?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, hierarchical-data

Anyone have an example of creating AND managing a hierarchy of users, where users (employees) can report to other users.

When a user leaves the company, their subordinates should be reassigned to the leaving users manager.  I suppose I could do that with a delete trigger.

Say I have a table like this.

```
   CREATE TABLE Employees
    (empid int NOT NULL,
     mgrid int NULL,
     empname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
     salary money NOT NULL,
     lvl int NULL,
     hierarchy varchar(900) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_Employees_empid PRIMARY KEY(empid),
     CONSTRAINT FK_Employees_mgrid_empid
       FOREIGN KEY(mgrid)
       REFERENCES Employees(empid))
```

Its easy enough to query for all the users who have a specific manager, but what happens when a manager gets reassigned...and all the users under them ?

[update]
I just discovered possibly a better way using the new SQL 2008 data type HierarchyId, reading this http://beyondrelational.com/modules/4/whatisnew/468/features/10585/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid-will-allows-you-to-efficiently-store-and-query-hierarchial-data.aspx

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: Another way of dealing with this type of hierarchy is to use nested sets. You can find tons of info about nested sets from google.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is wrong.  An employee should report to a position.  That position is filled by an employee.

Comment: I don't disagree with this but it does come with its own challenges. Often times as a company changes a given person will end up filling up multiple positions. This of course is easy enough to deal with but it is something the must be considered up front.

Comment: @SeanLange What part of that is is not addressed by my answer?   Nothing about that prevents an employee from filling more than one position.

Comment: I did not say that it didn't. I was trying to point out that you do not want to have a 1:1 between a person and a position.

Comment: @SeanLange And do you need to deal with a person reporting to more than 1 position.  Either way the answer is a correct data model and not these constraint hacks on the back end.

Comment: I agree. Not sure why you seem to be trying to convince me that you are correct. I was trying to point out some details to support your position.

Comment: @SeanLange And I am agreeing with you.  Need a proper data model up front.

Comment: +1000 * infinity on that!!! When the ddl is defined correctly, the dml is very easy.